# mysql_query update doesn't update

Tags: php, mysql

mysql_query running an UPDATE query isn't working for me, what am I doing wrong?

```
if($get_ip['user_ip']== ''){
    $insert_ip = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET user_ip='$user_ip' WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
     if(!$insert_ip){
         $message = 'invalid query'.mysql_error();
         die($message);
     }else{
         echo ('success!');
     };
};
```

Basically I am trying to update the table user at user_ip row with value ip_user, if user_ip field is empty of course.

So nothing updating and the user_ip filed remains empty please help.

Comment: does it return any error messages?

Comment: Added tag php since this is not pure mysql

Comment: I even tried using mysql_affected_rows() still nothing.

Comment: HAve you tried adding an else clause to be sure that you if doesnt evaluate to false?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `mysql_query`? It's the equivalent of writing SQL with a quill pen.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I can see on your script.

1. you are using `if($get_ip['user_ip']== '')` statement, which will insert data when `$get_ip['user_ip']` is only empty or it will ignore to insert data when `$get_ip['user_ip']` have some data.
2. You are using `SET user_ip='$user_ip'` on update query, I may not be correct, however I assume that you are trying to store data from `$get_ip['user_ip']`, if this is the situation use `SET user_ip='$get_ip['user_ip']'` instead of `SET user_ip='$user_ip'` on your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($get_ip['user_ip']== '')
```

won't work except if $get_ip['user_ip'] is empty.

use

```
if(!empty($get_ip['user_ip']))
```

instead

Comment: tried that too, not working as well. I know for a fact that the user_id field is empty

Comment: no errors thats why I'm confused, some kind of glitch or something

Comment: did you make mysql connection and database selection before these?

Comment: did that too of course. Connecting open, database selected too.

Comment: what is $get_ip? also how about echoing all the values you're using like echo "username: $username"; just to be sure everything is already set correctly, if not determine why you don't have what you expect.

Comment: 1) $get_ip is variable that I used for getting data from the row by using mysql_fetch_array.
so I echoed $get_ip['username'], password and others data and everything echoed correctly with values except ip because is empty

Answer (score 0):

There are just soooo many things wrong here, but in the interest of being helpful:

Assign the query string to variable rather than directly injecting it into the `mysql_query` function. Then, `echo` this string out. This will show you want you are sending to the database. Copy that output somewhere, and then log into whatever you use to manage your database (I assume it'll be phpMyAdmin). Open up your database and then the table you're targeting, and then use the query editor to run your query (paste the output you copied earlier).

- If your query string isn't what you expected, you have a code error.
- If your query is as you expected, and runs in the database tool, you
  likely have a permissions issue with the user account you're using in
  your connection string.
- If your query is as expected, but doesn't run correctly in your
  database tool, your problem most likely is a schema error.